# redirect output of command to /dev/null

Tags: shell-script, ssh, io-redirection, perl

I run the following line from my bash script in order to run the script /usr/run.pl on remote machines

```
  xargs -P "$numprocs" -I '{}' -n  1 -- perl -e 'alarm shift; exec @ARGV' -- "$timeout" ssh -nxaq -o ConnectTimeout=5 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no '{}' /usr/run.sh < <(echo -e "$node")
```

but I get on the console the following standard output

```
Connection to 143.6.22.4 closed by remote host.
 xargs: perl: exited with status 255; aborting
```

where I need to put the **1>/dev/null** in my syntax to avoid this message?

Comment: Stdio (standard out) is 1 (in this context) stderr is 2. 

I suspect you want to redirect stderr, meaning 2>/dev/null 

As to where, I'm not exactly sure what you're doing in that line so I would rather not hazard a guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two streams of output from a process that are generally sent to the terminal:  standard output (which is bound to file descriptor 1), and standard error (which is bound to file descriptor 2).  This allows for easily separated capture of expected output, and error messages or other diagnostic information that is not generally expected to be output.

When you use the redirect (`>`), that only kicks standard output to the specified file or location, leaving standard error untouched.  This allows you to see if there are errors (like those you are seeing).

If you want to send all output, including standard error, you need to redirect both streams:

```
/path/to/program arg1 arg2 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Or, alternatively but more explicitly:

```
/path/to/program arg1 arg2 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

The syntax `2>&1` means "Send output currently going to file descriptor 2 to the same place that output going to file descriptor 1 is going to".  `>` is omitting the default of FD1, so it is semantically the same as `1>`, which might make `2>` make more sense.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to show console/terminal logs of bash, use following command 
for example I start php server which generates request/response logs which I do not want, I do it with this command:

```
php -S localhost:8989 &> /dev/null
```